# Postgres version support for latest driver

Tags: postgresql

The postgres commnity has released the latest version

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Is it compatible from postgres version 8 on?

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the homepage](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

> This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using. It supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer and requires Java 6 or newer. It contains support for SSL and the javax.sql package.

---

But Postgres 8.x has [long be unsupported](http://Postgres%208.x%20isn't%20supported%20and%20shouldn't%20be%20used%20any%20more%20to%20begin%20with.) and shouldn't be used any more to begin with.